# CakePHP + JQM + Popup Widget = Why the appended 'placeholder'and empty content?

Tags: cakephp, jquery-mobile, popup

I'm about to kill someone and I'm thinking of the JQM team at the moment. Sigh!

So, clearly I'm doing something stupid.

I've populated a JQM popup div with some info from my database and on first page load, clicking the button with the popup's id as HREF works great!

When I submit the form and return to the same page, it doesn't work. Inspecting the element I see that the ID of the popup is appended with '-placeholder' and the div simply has a comment in it.

Problem: On page reload, I can't click on the HREF that links to the popup (or I can but nothing happens - obviously because the markup has vanished).

Here's the view code of 1. the link to the popup div and 2. the actual pop up div on first and second page load.

1. Linking to popup:

   <a href="#reqform_search_sicnaic" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="top" data-position-to="window" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" style="margin:12px auto 0px auto;">Browse Database</a>
2. Original popup div element

   <div id="reqform_search_sicnaic" data-role="popup">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
       Random Header
    </div>
       <div data-role="content">
       Random content
       </div>
   </div>
3. Popup div after form submission / second page load

   <div style="display: none;" id="reqform_search_sicnaic-placeholder"><!-- placeholder for reqform_search_sicnaic --></div>

Obviously, I can't open the dialog on page load. :(

Comment: This is not your problem, each time popup is hidden it will have -placeholder sulfix. Just look at hidden popup HTML first time you open your page. Are you doing anything programmatically through JavaScript or is this pure HTML markup error?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying....

Comment: Just look at a popup HTML (use browser web developer tools) while it is hidden (just after your page initializes for the first time).

Comment: Ah, quite right you are. Any other potentially related issue that the popup won't work on second page load. At least anything obvious that wouldn't required further debugging??

Comment: I'll help you tomorrow, I need to lick my wounds first, we just lost against Brazil. ;)

Comment: Lol, that own goal was a bit of a sting ;)